# Japerserver exception getting dataset from cache

Tags: jasperserver

I am using jasperserver with Mongodb as data source. I have added the data source, test connection is successful. but after creating a topic when i try to create an ad hoc view for the report it gives me

```
The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.


Error Message

java.lang.RuntimeException: exception getting dataset from cache

Error Trace

java.lang.RuntimeException: exception getting dataset from cache at com.jaspersoft.commons.semantic.dsimpl.memory.MemoryDataSet.getWorkingDataSet(MemoryDataSet.java:184) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.NewClassicDataStrategy.getWorkingDataSet(NewClassicDataStrategy.java:120) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.CommonDomainDataStrategy.getWorkingDataSet(CommonDomainDataStrategy.java:1026) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.InteractiveDataLayoutEngine.initWorkingDataSet(InteractiveDataLayoutEngine.java:350) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.InteractiveCrosstabBaseEngine$DimensionDataSetInitializer.initDimensionDataSet(InteractiveCrosstabBaseEngine.java:101) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.InteractiveCrosstabBaseEngine$DimensionDataSetInitializer.init(InteractiveCrosstabBaseEngine.java:81) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.InteractiveIntelligentChartEngine.generateViewModel(InteractiveIntelligentChartEngine.java:113) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.action.AdhocAction.setReportModelInContext(AdhocAction.java:1495) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.action.AdhocAction.view(AdhocAction.java:593) at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.action.AdhocAction.initForTopic(AdhocAction.java:454) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor976.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) at org.springframework.webflow.action.DispatchMethodInvoker.invoke(DispatchMethodInvoker.java:98) at org.springframework.webflow.action.MultiAction.doExecute(MultiAction.java:123) at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188) at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51) at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77) at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188) at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145) at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261) at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor241.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) at org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:66) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) at sun.proxy.$Proxy144.resumeExecution(Unknown Source) at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183) at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.doFilter(StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.java:112) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.IPadSupportFilter.doFilter(IPadSupportFilter.java:67) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.java:154) at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101) at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:94) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.multipleTenancy.MTBasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(MTBasicProcessingFilter.java:182) at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:209) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278) at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.ji.license.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:96) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.ji.license.JILicenseFilter.doFilter(JILicenseFilter.java:67) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.UserPreferencesFilter.doFilter(UserPreferencesFilter.java:209) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.filter.BasicLoggingFilter.doFilter(BasicLoggingFilter.java:53) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.JSCsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(JSCsrfGuardFilter.java:83) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.WebAppSecurityFilter.doFilter(WebAppSecurityFilter.java:76) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.MultipartRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(MultipartRequestWrapperFilter.java:90) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.encryption.EncryptionFilter.doFilter(EncryptionFilter.java:130) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235) at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.SessionDecoratorFilter.doFilter(SessionDecoratorFilter.java:43) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:67) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.P3PFilter.doFilter(P3PFilter.java:43) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) Caused by: com.jaspersoft.commons.dataset.DataSetException: exception fetching from cache at com.jaspersoft.commons.datarator.BaseDataSetCacheImpl.getWorkingDataSet(BaseDataSetCacheImpl.java:142) at com.jaspersoft.commons.semantic.dsimpl.memory.MemoryDataSet.getWorkingDataSet(MemoryDataSet.java:97) ... 139 more Caused by: com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: exception fetching from cache at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.strategy.CommonDomainDataStrategy$CacheListener.stateChanged(CommonDomainDataStrategy.java:1127) at com.jaspersoft.commons.datarator.CachedData.setState(CachedData.java:187) at com.jaspersoft.commons.datarator.CachedData.setThrowable(CachedData.java:199) at com.jaspersoft.commons.datarator.CachedData.fetchData(CachedData.java:169) at com.jaspersoft.commons.datarator.BaseDataSetCacheImpl.getWorkingDataSet(BaseDataSetCacheImpl.java:139) ... 140 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: passed value of class java.lang.String to DateColumn.set(), expecting subclass of java.util.Date at com.jaspersoft.commons.datarator.DataColumnFactory$DateAdapter.convert(DataColumnFactory.java:288) at com.jaspersoft.commons.datarator.DataColumnFactory$DateAdapter.set(DataColumnFactory.java:271) at com.jaspersoft.commons.datarator.CategorizedColumn.set(CategorizedColumn.java:63) at com.jaspersoft.commons.datarator.SelfOptimizingColumn.set(SelfOptimizingColumn.java:47) at com.jaspersoft.commons.datarator.ColumnDataSet.setObject(ColumnDataSet.java:97) at com.jaspersoft.commons.datarator.CachedData.fetchData(CachedData.java:150) ... 141 more
```

Need help thanks

Comment: Please can you re-format the stacktrace to be more readable. Also, by diving into it you will see `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: passed value of class java.lang.String to DateColumn.set(), expecting subclass of java.util.Date`. I'm guessing you are formatting a date field but MongoDB returns a String in a format that can't be converted to Date directly

Comment: @JScoobyCed that was what was wrong for me. Works !

Comment: @JScoobyCed Thanks ! found that field . it worked .